# telnet end of message

Tags: c, sockets, ftp, telnet

I'm trying to interact with ftp server (specifically it's a ftp.de.debian.org) using my own telnet client. It's working, but after anonymous login ftp server sends welcome message - it can send data in different packages (am i right?), and when it happens - i can't read it from socket as a whole message. When i use GNU telnet client - welcome message prints all at once.

I tried use select syscall, non blocking sockets, but result is the same - chunk of data received, socket ready, data printed out.
Current implementation of "receive response" function:

```
void recv_response(int fd, char *resp_buff, int buff_size) {

    memset(resp_buff, 0, 1024);

    fd_set rfds;
    struct timeval time;
    int ret_val;

    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(fd, &rfds);

    time.tv_sec = 1;
    time.tv_usec = 0;

    if ((ret_val = recv(fd, resp_buff, 1024, 0)) < 0 && errno != EAGAIN) {
        exit_on_error();
    } else {
        select(fd+1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &time);
        ret_val = recv(fd, resp_buff, 1024, 0);
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", ret_val);
        printf("%s\n", resp_buff);
    }

}
```

I got proper result only using sleep for 1 sec before reading from socket.

Example of strace with GNU telnet client shows that recvfrom got fragmented message, first part is 142 and other is 157.

```
recvfrom(3, "230- Welcome to ftp.de.debian.or"..., 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 142
select(4, [0 3], [1], [3], {0, 0})      = 1 (out [1], left {0, 0})
write(1, "230- Welcome to ftp.de.debian.or"..., 139230- Welcome to ftp.de.debian.org,
          hosted at Faculty of Computer Science,
                   Technische Universitaet Dresden, Germany.
) = 139
select(4, [0 3], [], [3], NULL)         = 1 (in [3])
recvfrom(3, " \r\n  If have any unusual problem"..., 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 157
select(4, [0 3], [1], [3], {0, 0})      = 1 (out [1], left {0, 0})
write(1, " \n  If have any unusual problems"..., 152 
  If have any unusual problems,
  please report them via e-mail to:      ftpadm@inf.tu-dresden.de

230 Anonymous access granted, restrictions apply
) = 152
```

So, how telnet client determined there is another part and first part should not be printed until second arrived?

Comment: As you can see from strace log - second part of message starts with '\r\n', so if i try recv in loop until '\n' - i'll get only part of whole message. The thing is - data is fragmented and there is '\n' in each fragment at the end.

Comment: You're calling `recv()` twice without processing the data from the first call. *Ergo* whatever other problems you may have, you are certainly losing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to communicate with an ftp server, you will have to implement ftp transfer protocol at least at the level to be able to split the input stream into messages. You can find the specification of ftp protocol for example here: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt. Concerning ftp message format it says:

> A reply is defined to contain the 3-digit code, followed by Space
>         , followed by one line of text (where some maximum line length
>         has been specified), and terminated by the Telnet end-of-line
>         code. There will be cases however, where the text is longer than
>         a single line.  In these cases the complete text must be bracketed
>         so the User-process knows when it may stop reading the reply (i.e.
>         stop processing input on the control connection) and go do other
>         things.  This requires a special format on the first line to
>         indicate that more than one line is coming, and another on the
>         last line to designate it as the last.  At least one of these must
>         contain the appropriate reply code to indicate the state of the
>         transaction.  To satisfy all factions, it was decided that both
>         the first and last line codes should be the same.
>
> Thus the format for multi-line replies is that the first line
>            will begin with the exact required reply code, followed
>            immediately by a Hyphen, "-" (also known as Minus), followed by
>            text.  The last line will begin with the same code, followed
>            immediately by Space , optionally some text, and the Telnet
>            end-of-line code.

```
        For example:
                            123-First line
                            Second line
                              234 A line beginning with numbers
                            123 The last line
```

Note that there is no correspondance between the number of executed `recv`s and the number of messages sent by the server. TCP/IP connection is just a stream of bytes and can be broken into chunks or joined together by any router on the road as well as by your own system.

Answer (score 0):

```
// you need to know how to determine if whole message has been received.

// in general, for the first char of input, use a longish wait time
// for following characters use a very short wait time.
// do this in a sequence like:

// set number of char read to 0
// set timeout to message start wait time
// while(1)
//     selectReturn = select() using timeout
//     if 0 == selectReturn (timeout event occurred, no message available or all chars read)
//     then exit loop

//     if(0 >  selectReturn (error occurred, exit loop to handle error
//     then exit loop

//     if 0 < selectReturn then
//     then, 
//        read a char and toss
//        incr number of char read, (for later comparison for validity)
//        set timeout to inter char wait time
//     end if
// end while

//
```

Comment: Select returns the number of descriptors on success and -1 on error, thus if(0 >  selectReturn) - it's not 'error occured' as you assumed. Anyway, all will end at this - if (0 == selectReturn), because after first chunk of data arrived select call returns 0 and message will be printed - and it's only part of a whole. As i said in my frist message - i tried it.

Answer (score 0):

In real, telnet does *not* does the thing you described. You can see this comparing input and output. It got 142 octets and print 139 bytes (network-style CRLF line ending is translated to single LF), but without terminator of the first response line. Then, the second chunk starts with line terminator of the first response line. So, the telnet client relays its input as is, without any groupping.

There are two things principally important here:

1. Telnet client doesn't block on input from any side. It can provide some complex logic of switching local and remote disciplines (line buffering or no buffering, with local echo and without one, etc.), but all this logic activates only under specific circumstances (telnet to port 23, control sequences from remote server, explicit local option), and is "sleeping" in your example. By default, local terminate discipline is configured for line buffering, so, your requests won't be sent to telnet from your terminal until Enter is pressed. OTOH, remote data is printed immediately. This can result in some mess on screen if remote doesn't wait for your requests.
2. FTP has its own structure which declares that responses are sent using special syntax. Particularly, any response line starts with digit code, and this code is followed with hyphen instead of space if this line isn't the last response line. So, FTP client reads lines (each line shall be terminated with CRLF to be treated as properly received) and, if detected the line has continuation sign ('-' after initial digits), waits for a next one.

For further progress, please specify what you exactly try to reach. Is this telnet client, FTP client, or something another?

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'm trying to implement telnet client (simple version of gnu telnet client) and i also wanted to know how checking response code from ftp server implemented in gnu telnet version, read source code, but couldn't figure it out anyway.

Comment: telnet itself doesn't check any FTP response code. If you use telnet to chat with FTP server, this is a human's responsibility. That's why you couldn't found how checking response code is implemented - the proper answer is "no way, it isn't". For such check you should read FTP client source code, not telnet one.

Comment: I know telnet doesn't have to check FTP response code, i expressed myself wrong, i just want to now how gnu telnet client interprets (and prints) that welcome message as a whole, even it's arrived fragmented? Based on what telnet client made decision NOT to print first arrived fragment?

Comment: Please explain, why do you say telnet "made decision NOT to print first arrived fragment" if your strace output explicitly says telnet _did_ print the fragment?

Comment: Yes, you're right, there is two write calls in strace log, sorry for my inattention. The question remains - how gnu telnet client performing writing data from buffer to stdout.

Comment: It simply writes data to stdout.:) Well, not so simply - it converts network CRLF line terminators to local LF ones. OTOH it's event-driven with `select()` around reading two descriptors - stdin (0) and network one. If some data are available to read, it reads, converts and passes to opposite side output buffers. If there is something in output buffers, it adds waiting to write a corresponding descriptor, and, if it can, writes. That's all if the telnet protocol specifics aren't applied.